# Which is better for task management?

Tags: azure-devops, devops

Microsoft Planner or Azure DevOps
We need to keep a track of tasks assigned to DevOps teammates.
I checked Azure Devops.
Azure DevOps gives you tasks and issue so that you can assign it to the members.
Not sure what MS Planner offers and should we chose that over Azure DevOps

Answer (score 2):

**Microsoft Planner** is a task planning tool integrated in Office 365.

The level of capability from low to higher is corresponding  task management to project portfolio management.

For a detail tutorial you could take a look at this link: [Microsoft Planner - Step-by-step guide for users](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p82hS0K32fA)

**Azure DevOps** is a cloud-side source code management system also offering project management features as part of Microsoft's application life cycle management solutions. More project management features are accessible.

In Azure DevOps, you could also track work with Kanban boards, backlogs, team dashboards, and custom reporting.

Combine drag-and-drop sprint planning and flexible work item tracking with comprehensive traceability to have the perfect home for all your ideas–big and small.

[image]

You could also use the visualization options provided by Delivery Plans to review the schedule of stories or features your teams plan to deliver. Delivery Plans show the scheduled work items by sprint (iteration path) of selected teams against a calendar view.

Delivery plans is also interactive. You can change the assigned sprint of a work item by dragging it to a new sprint as shown in the above image.

---

I couldn't directly give you an accurate answer which one is better, it's all based on you and your team's requirement. They are totally two different products. Please kindly select the one suitable for your sides.